# React native elements error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am trying to use `FormValidationMessage` from react-native-elements. I don't see what I am doing wrong. I get the error:

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I import just like the [docs](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/forms.html#formvalidationmessage):

```
import { Input, Button, FormValidationMessage } from 'react-native-elements';
```

My function that uses it:

```
showLoginError() {
    console.log(this.props.error); //I can log the correct error here
    if (this.props.error) {
      return(
        <FormValidationMessage>{this.props.error}</FormValidationMessage>
      )
    }
}
```

I am directly calling this function in render like this

```
<View style={{width: 250}}>
   {this.showLoginError()}
</View>
```

I looked all over the internet but doesn't seem like there is a clear solution.

Comment: `this.props.error` What does the error looks like? is it an object, a string or some other type of data?

Comment: @remelkabir it's a string. I am using react-redux and it is set in my reducer. I can log it just fine right before my return.

Comment: Looks like they have taken the component out of their codebase, but they didn't update their docs. @jacobmarsellos
https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/c668c78dddd9315f6ca5ec2548e051b2a7e29c73/website/blog/2019-01-27-1.0-release.md#form

Comment: Well it's a community project. You can always make a Pull request to update the docs yourself, if you have the time. :) 
I would recommend using this as the docs instead of the readme. https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/

Comment: Also you might be reading docs for the wrong version of the library. Make sure the docs version matches your package.json's version.

Comment: Thanks, if you post the above as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like they have taken the component out of their codebase, in their latest release.

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/c668c78dddd9315f6ca5ec2548e051b2a7e29c73/website/blog/2019-01-27-1.0-release.md#form

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed this seems to be the case! Do you have any idea how to solve this problem now?

Comment: I would look for a similar component within react-native-elements or write a custom one as per the need.

Comment: Thanks @remelkabir - actually after reading the docs I found that in react-native-elements itself, they have moved this functionality to the <Input> component which can receive 'error' as a prop.

Comment: updated link https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/2019/01/27/1.0-release.html#form

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your function return null in the case that there is no error.

```
showLoginError() {
  console.log(this.props.error); //I can log the correct error here
  if (this.props.error) {
    return(
      <FormValidationMessage>{this.props.error}</FormValidationMessage>
    )
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case (using Webpack) it was the difference between:

```
import {MyComponent} from '../components/xyz.js';
```

vs

```
import MyComponent from '../components/xyz.js';
```

The second one works while the first caused the error.

Comment: This does not help. I am doing the same as in the doc: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/forms.html#formvalidationmessage